# Cannot set input on the same line with small dimension

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to add two input field on the same line with the minimum dimension, I tried this:

```
<div class="row">
 <input type="number" class="form-control" class="slider-start" data-id="1">
 <input type="number" class="form-control" class="slider-end" data-id="1">
</div>
```

[this is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m9Lbdufk/)

Comment: Upgrade to the latest version of bootstrap 4 (the version in your fiddle is out of date and doesn't work properly) then you can just wrap them in col divs: https://www.bootply.com/rNrVlSyNM8

Comment: If you're using the latest version of BS then you can add `d-flex` to the row.
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/flex/

Comment: @Rafael the row is `display: flex` itself.

Comment: thanks @Pete it works

Comment: @Pete is possible increase the width of the col?

Comment: use the col class corresponding to the width you want

Comment: The difference between my answer and @Pete comment is that the "col" class uses as much width space as possible on the screen, making each input fill a whole "line". But "col-auto", on the contrary, uses as little space on a same line as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `inline-flex` inside your style.

```
<div class="row" style="display: inline-flex;">
  <input type="number" class="form-control" class="slider-start" data-id="1">
  <input type="number" class="form-control" class="slider-end" data-id="1">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox should help you.

```
.form-control{
  width: 35%; /*size of input box*/
  flex-flow: row nowrap; /*sets flex-box elements order*/
}

.row {
  display: flex;
}
```

I hope that I helped.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-auto">
            <input type="number" class="form-control" class="slider-start" data-id="1">
        </div>
        <div class="col-auto">
            <input type="number" class="form-control" class="slider-end" data-id="1">
        </div>
    </div>
```